# start_urls in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to fetch some information from this website: http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat.
As you can see, the table has a pagination, so whenever you click second or third page, the link will change too something http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=20 (with the "start=" at the end). 
This is my spider code:

```
allowed_domains = ["go-on.fi"]
start_urls = ["http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=0"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []
    titles = hxs.select("//tr")

    for row in titles:
        item = JobData()
        item['header'] = row.select("./td[1]/a/text()").extract()
        item['link'] = row.select("./td[1]/a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
```

So my question is, how can I make the spider go through every page of the website (I mean the table page)?

Comment: Are there always 20 entries per page? If so, just build your URLs in a for loop, and break out of the loop when you get a 404 error on attempting to read a non-existent page.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set the start_urls to the main page then based on the number of pages shown in the footer pagination (in this case 3), use a loop to create a yield Request for each of the pages:

```
allowed_domains = ["go-on.fi"]
start_urls = ["http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat"]

def parse(self, response):
    pages = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination"][last()-1]/a/text()').extract()
    page = 1
    start = 0
    while page <= pages:
        url = "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start="+str(start)
        start += 20
        page += 1
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []
    titles = hxs.select("//tr")

    for row in titles:
        item = JobData()
        item['header'] = row.select("./td[1]/a/text()").extract()
        item['link'] = row.select("./td[1]/a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
```