# How to get data from subsequent urls with scrappy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to fetch data from this website: http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat with Scrappy.
I am able to fetch the data from this page which have href move to another page when you click on the first column title.
My question is how can I lead the spider to go deeper to for example this link: http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat/oulu/11414 and get information from there.
so this is my code at this moment:

```
class JobDataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "jobdata"
    allowed_domains = ["go-on.fi"]

    start_urls = ["http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=0",
                  "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=20",
                  "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=40",
                  "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=60"
                  ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        jobs = hxs.select("//tr")

        for row in jobs:
            item = JobData()
            item['title'] = row.select("./td[1]/a/text()").extract()
            item['link'] = row.select("./td[1]/a/@href").extract()
            item['location'] = row.select("./td[2]/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to yield Request(url) for each of the URl's found on the first page.  Something like this should work:

```
class JobDataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "jobdata"
    allowed_domains = ["go-on.fi"]

    start_urls = ["http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=0",
                  "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=20",
                  "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=40",
                  "http://www.go-on.fi/tyopaikat?start=60"
                ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        links = hxs.xpath("//tr/td[1]/a/@href").extract()
        for l in links:
            yield Request(l, callback=self.parse_pages)

    def parse_pages(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = JobData()
        item['link'] = response.url
        etc....
```

Comment: Is it an ongoing issue ? Code is very similar to this yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410071/start-urls-in-scrapy/28417298#28417298

Comment: Maybe he didn't read my previous answer :) It's slightly different, but not enough to warrant another question.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot for the answer. I almost at figure out the problem by my self during the time I waiting for the answer.
My solution is something like you, but instead of "yield" I use "return" so code doesn't work like what I expect